# Code generation failed: Unrecognized flag '-FitObjData' in 'p2'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

I am getting this error "Unrecognized flag '-FitObjData' in 'p2'" after adding libpng static library to my project for use with pngwriter. How do I fix this error and what is it telling me? I am compiling with VC10.

Comment: Looks like an error in a back-end module (like `cl.exe`'s `c1xx.dll` and `c2.dll`), but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot those.  Try looking for any "weird" flags anywhere in `cl` or `link`'s command line.  If you can't see any, try using your library with some other program, and see if you get the same error.

Comment: I had to do a complete rebuild to fix this error.

Answer (score 8):

I also encountered this issue while trying to link with openssl.

The issue was openssl was built by visual 2015 and I was linking with visual 2012. This difference might trigger some dark magic in the visual studio backend.

Try to recompile your static library with visual 2010.

Comment: 100% lifesaver. There's some dark magic in the backend indeed

Comment: I'm also having a similar `C1007: unrecognized flag '-Yu' in 'p2'` when linking static libs compiled with VS2019 and linking in VS2017. They are definetely not ABI compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If your solution has multiple projects and build configurations, make sure you update the target platform for all projects and build configurations.

I ran into this problem after updating from VS 2010 to VS 2015. One project failed to build in Debug configuration because a library it depended on (in the same solution) was still being built (in its Debug configuration) with Platform Toolset = "Visual Studio 2010". Updating that to "Visual Studio 2015 (v140)" fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need to rebuild nything, depending on your Visual Studio installations and what you want to do.

I had two installations, VS-2017 and VS-2019. My `$PATH` selected `lib.exe` of the 2017th edition, but Extension.obj was built with the 2019th edition. I just put the full path to the 2019 lib.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\Hostx86\x86\lib.exe" /out:Extension.lib Extension.obj
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to some libraries that u are linking were built on some differernt visual studio version . clean and rebuilt all dependencies . than the linking will be proper.

Answer (score -1):

I've got this error to build a project in Visual Studio while it is dependent to another project which was built with another version of Visual Studio. To solve this problem, make sure all projects and their dependencies are compatible.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34763415)